# Can't get basic oscillator to make noise using the Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Can't get the oscillator to make noise? Think I'm missing something obvious but no idea really. Following https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createOscillator

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Audio API</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

      var oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();

      oscillator.type = 'square';
      oscillator.frequency.value = 3000;
      oscillator.start();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the oscillator node to an audio destination:

```
 oscillator.frequency.value = 3000;
 oscillator.connect( audioContext.destination );
 oscillator.start();
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tested your solution but believe it is the correct one as this was how I fixed the problem after my own further investigation last night.